# Parallel.ForEach with async lambda waiting forall iterations to complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

recently I have seen several SO threads related to Parallel.ForEach mixed with async lambdas, but all proposed answers were some kind of workarounds.

Is there any way how could I write:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>[]();

Parallel.ForEach(arrayValues, async (item) =>
{
  var x = await LongRunningIoOperationAsync(item);
  list.Add(x);
});
```

How can I ensure that list will contain all items from all iterations executed withing lambdas in each iteration?

How will generally Parallel.ForEach work with async lambdas, if it hit await will it hand over its thread to next iteration?

I assume ParallelLoopResult IsCompleted field is not proper one, as it will return true when all iterations are executed, no matter if their actual lambda jobs are finished or not?

Comment: await would force the task thread to be released and it doesnt gaurantee that same thread will continue when awaited task finishes. But yes the Parallel ForEach would guarantee that all iterations completed and x's were added to list unless an exception happened.

Comment: You'd be better off with `var results = await Task.WhenAll(arrayvalues.Select(x => LongRunningIoOperationAsync(x)))`.  Parallel is better suited for CPU bound work, not IO bound.

Comment: Your implementation is not thread-safe. You can't call `list.Add(x)` inside the `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: @ldragicevic if you want to limit the amount of concurrent asynchronous operations look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> recently I have seen several SO threads related to Parallel.ForEach mixed with async lambdas, but all proposed answers were some kind of workarounds.

Well, that's because `Parallel` *doesn't work* with `async`. And from a different perspective, why would you want to mix them in the first place? They do *opposite things*. `Parallel` is all about adding threads and `async` is all about giving up threads. If you want to do asynchronous work concurrently, then use `Task.WhenAll`. That's the correct tool for the job; `Parallel` is not.

That said, it sounds like you want to use the wrong tool, so here's how you do it...

> How can I ensure that list will contain all items from all iterations executed withing lambdas in each iteration?

You'll need to have some kind of a signal that some code can block on until the processing is done, e.g., `CountdownEvent` or `Monitor`. On a side note, you'll need to protect access to the non-thread-safe `List<T>` as well.

> How will generally Parallel.ForEach work with async lambdas, if it hit await will it hand over its thread to next iteration?

Since `Parallel` doesn't understand `async` lambdas, when the first `await` yields (returns) to its caller, `Parallel` will assume that interation of the loop is complete.

> I assume ParallelLoopResult IsCompleted field is not proper one, as it will return true when all iterations are executed, no matter if their actual lambda jobs are finished or not?

Correct. As far as `Parallel` knows, it can only "see" the method to the first `await` that returns to its caller. So it doesn't know when the `async` lambda is complete. It also will assume iterations are complete too early, which throws partitioning off.

Comment: Always a good read and eloquently written. note to @ldragicevic your accepted vote should go here

Comment: Yeah, definitely. @Stephen big thanks for the clarification! It makes totally more sense having these facts in mind.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `Parallel.For/ForEach` here you just need to *await* a list of tasks.

**Background**

In short you need to be very careful about *async lambdas*, and if you are passing them to an `Action` or `Func<Task>`

Your problem is because `Parallel.For / ForEach` is not suited for the *async and await pattern* or *IO bound tasks*. They are suited for *cpu bound workloads*. Which means they essentially have `Action` parameters and let's the *task scheduler* create the *tasks* for you

If you want to run multiple *async* tasks at the same time use `Task.WhenAll` , or a *TPL Dataflow* *Block* (or something similar) which can deal effectively with both *CPU bound* and *IO bound* works loads, or said more directly, they can deal with *tasks* which is what an *async method* is.

Unless you need to do more inside of your lambda (for which you haven't shown), just use a`Select` and `WhenAll`

```
var tasks = items .Select(LongRunningIoOperationAsync);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // here is your list of int
```

If you do, you can still use the await,

```
var tasks = items.Select(async (item) =>
   {
       var x = await LongRunningIoOperationAsync(item);
       // do other stuff
       return x;
   });

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

<sub>***Note*** : If you need the extended functionality of `Parallel.ForEach` (namely the Options to control max concurrency), there are several approach, however RX or DataFlow might be the most succinct</sub>

Comment: thanks, I am a bit curious only if c# program could handle any length of items e.g. if I pass 1000 items would it be smart to schedule some limited number of threads to execute all 1000 tasks in batches of a smaller number of threads

Comment: @ldragicevic the default task scheduler will take care limiting concurrency depending on the workloads, cores and heuristics

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was only worried if I would need to handle resources for parallelism, but according to previous comment, it's ok.